# After changing domain name of wordpress site only default permalinks working wordpress others returns 404 error

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I will be really thankfull for any help, because After reading and trying a lot of tutorials, i have not found any solution.
After i change domain name from www.examlpe.fr to www.newExample.fr, i have only the home page works successfully but others links returns 404 not found error. I try to manage this with Permalinks, i found only the default permalink works.

in wp_config i set:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://newExample.fr' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://newExample.fr' );
```

Also in functions.php i set:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://newExample.fr' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://newExample.fr' );
```

my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

In addition, i try to update .htaccess(to make an old one and to create a blank one) file and edit permissions while editing primalinks

Also i have change in mysite.conf to replace   AllowOverride None -->  AllowOverride All

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: can you check for the permission of the your server uploaded folder. Also ask your server help centre. might be they will help you.

Comment: @Nidhi Patel thank you for replying quickly, i forget to mention that i have an ftp access. Otherwise i'll ask my server help center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's resolved i'm sure from the beginnig that was the activation of rewrite rules from my server center.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your WordPress dashboard? If so try to go there under settings -> permalinks just open that page and press save once. After that your sites should work.

Answer (score 0):

For 4 years I use *Search-Replace-DB* to fix that kind of issues. Wordpress keep in your DB the old urls. *First you need to download and read the README [Search-Replace-DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB)*

**Try follow the next step:**

1- Copy the whole folder inside your wordpress site. I assume you download or clone the previously repository link.

```
mv Search-Replace-DB /my/web/site
```

2- open a browser and go to `mydomain.com/Search-Replace-DB`

You will get a dashboard very nice, its very intuitive.