# Only default permalinks working WordPress, others permalinks options becomes 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

My problem is in my WordPress site only default permalinks are working. When I change permalinks all pages become not found (404). The home page and the shop page is the only working with post name.

Before this problem, I have one more question. that was my site was hacked or may be due to plugin it has some unnecessary files which redirect to some dating site. But I have checked them and delete using WordFence Wordpress plugin. The site is clean now!

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**What I did so far?**

- Change permalinks type and save twist. (nothing work even in a private window)
- Change rewrite mode in the database file (clear that field empty and change permalink type. not work)

***Which plugin I have used?**

- Really Simple SSL
- Wordfence Security (pro)

Other plugin related to the theme such as slider revolution, WooCommerce, Contact Form 7 etc. I think they are not that critical to this problem.

I have checked these posts:

[only default permalinks working wordpress others become 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500758/only-default-permalinks-working-wordpress-others-become-404-error)

[After changing domain name of wordpress site only default permalinks working wordpress others returns 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973585/after-changing-domain-name-of-wordpress-site-only-default-permalinks-working-wor)

Non of answer work for me. That why I'm post this as a new question here. Also i have post this to [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/362869/only-default-permalinks-working-wordpress-others-become-404-error) couldn't find an answer yet.

Thank you

Comment: Verify that the 'rewrite' module is loaded. Create a phpinfo() page and make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. What you mean by Create a phpinfo() page?

Comment: I meant, create any simple PHP page in your root folder & try to embed <?php phpinfo() ?> inside the file and run it.  You will get compiled information about your PHP environment and search for the module call mod_rewrite. The module should be enabled to run permalinks in WordPress.
[More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server/37693775)